# How to find out the processor core on which the process was started in Linux?

Tags: linux, pid, utility

I know the process PID, and this program consumes a lot of resources. My computer has 2 processor cores.  I want to know, on which core the process was started.

Comment: you can nail a process to a specific core with `taskset`

Comment: If there were an answer to this question, then it would be not very useful. Unless you explicitly bind process to specific CPU, the process may migrate from one CPU to another one many times per second. If for some reason you _really_ need to know where it was originally started, you can subscribe to "sched_*" events with `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/` (search on the web how to do it).